# Как сделать топ 5 участников

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

Пишу небольшого бота ВК на python. Мне нужно реализовать топ по сообщениям. Работаю с mysql.
у меня есть таблица users в которой есть колонка msg. Остаётся вопрос как вывести 5 участников по убыванию с максимальными кол-во сообщениями.

Comment: `ORDER BY msq LIMIT 5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот ссылка на сортировку элементов в mysql: https://oracleplsql.ru/order-by-mysql.html . В данном случае вам нужно после ORDER BY msg добавить DESC, т.к. вам надо от большего к меньшему, а DESC сортирует в порядке убывания. Ну и после всего прописать LIMIT 5 для вывода только 5 человек. Подробные примеры использования ORDER BY вы найдете по ссылке.